# How can I open some website (for example stackoverflow) in some place in my site?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, web

I saw some online anonymizers make it so I can even browse the web right from their page.

I want to open some website ins some `<div`, or maybe `<asp` panel in my web site

how can I make it?

Comment: The wonder is your 4295 reps! And the your post! Both are contrasting

Comment: Sorry, don't get it. Is this question is that easy for people who have this counts, why so?

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to offend but this question is very silly, unless you are not exposed to .com era , this becomes par of your basic HTML learning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you want an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)? It stands for inline frame, and is the HTML5 and beyond replacement for regular frames.

Comment: Note that not all sites allow you to show them inside an iframe. StackOverflow is like this.

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com) won't work in `<iframe>` too. `Header set X-Frame-Options DENY`

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the ASP.NET with a Browser Control.

Hit up this link from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET) to see a custom wrapper for a Browser Control.

or you could create try using HttpWebRequest to load the remote site and then display it on your site.

You might check out this [tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/49/How-to-read-a-remote-web-page-with-ASP.NET-2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do that with Iframe.

Following is example for that.

```
<iframe src="URL" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't allow to be in iframe

Comment: @nCdy Stackoverflow is just for example, person dont want to put stackoverflow in his/her website.

Comment: StackOverflow... maybe, but I'm sure that person wants github... and seems like it's not possible too so person is thinking about it's API for displaying repositories list with a links.

Comment: ya that also possible but i just want to give easy way.